# Set privacy when publishing an action

Tags: privacy, facebook-timeline

Have anyone heard Facebook say anything about adding the possibility to specify the privacy when publishing an action? I wonder if it's something they plan for the near future or if it will take longer time for them to implement.

### Background

The "App activity privacy" let's the user set who should be able to see actions published by the app. I would like my app to set the privacy **for each and every action** the app publishes, just as an app can do for wall posts by specifying the "privacy" field.

### Edit 2012-05-24

I attended Facebook Developer Garage in Stockholm yesterday and had the opportunity to ask what Facebook's plan is. The answer was that Facebook did think a lot about adding flexible privacy settings, but decided that they want it as simple as possible for the user. They want to let the user decide the privacy settings for everything the app publishes once and the users can currently do this when they add the app. You never know when Facebook change their minds but currently they don't have a plan for decent privacy settings.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook have now added the "privacy" parameter when publishing actions.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/

Case closed.

Edit: As Angel García Olloqui pointed out, the privacy field can only have the values ALL_FRIENDS or SELF. Pretty useless for now.

Edit: I added a more complete answer to the question.

Comment: Well, it supports privacy but only ALL_FRIENDS and SELF, which is almost the same that do not support privacy at all (in general there is little point on creating an action in FB just for yourself)

Comment: True! I didn't see that detail before. Thanks!

Comment: Angel, I got an answer from a few developers at Facebook. Please see my edit of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Access token generates corresponding to your all permissions which appear on the first startup of the application.  Then by using that access token app enables to get some information from user

Comment: Sry, but you didn't understood the question. The question is about "actions" which are the things visible in the ticker and aggregated in the timeline.